# Is there a way to run multiple Spring Boot applications with a single Running Configuration in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot, run-configuration

I have multiple spring boot applications in a single IntelliJ project. And i want to have a single button to run all of them in some order.

I know there is an option to `Run Another configuration` before launching the original one, so in that way the configurations can be chained.

But when i use it, it runs that Another Configuration and doesn't run the original one.

So I'm wondering if anyone met this issue and how it was resolved?

Comment: Have you tried making a script (bash/bat etc.) that runs them all then just running the script?

Comment: Or installed [this plugin?](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248?pr=idea)
Not sure how trustworthy/good it is, but it exists for this purpose...

Comment: @Harmelodic yes, the script is a good option but i felt like there should be a solution from the box in IDEA. And it does exist :)

Comment: Compound is better for development and out of IDEA, but if you want to stagger start up, as well as possibly automate deployment in the future (through a CI server, etc.), scripting might be a better choice. Or a combination of the two; to maximize the efficiency and advantages of both systems!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could create a `Compound` run type and add all your applications in it. That way you can just run that config and all your apps will start.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. The only question i have on my mind is if there's a way to add some delay or tell one service to wait until another's up. For instance, i have config-service which is required for other ones other and i want to make sure that all my dependent services won't fail because the config is still getting up.

Comment: Thank you, you're beautiful! Much quicker fix compared to a gradle script which creates an executable jar and runs each of them separately...annoyingly time consuming to figure out when each app is in different modules...

Answer (score 15):

Update April 2016:

Multirun Plugin says:
**Prefer to use built-in support starting from IntelliJIdea 15 https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-compound.html**

Stéphane's answer works great but if you need additional features you can install the `MultiRun Plugin` that will allow you to do the same as the `Compound` run type but with more bells and whistles.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248

For instance:
You can set a delay between each configuration run or run one configuration after another using the Before Launch feature.

[image: Multirun Plugin]

See here for more info about how to setup: https://github.com/rkhmelyuk/multirun/wiki/How-to-run-configurations-with-Multirun

Comment: Very helpful answer.
Just a note, if you are trying to set delay (let's say 10 seconds), set it like "10", not like "10,0" since it will not apply it.

Answer (score 4):

**Env**:

- **IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3** (Ultimate Edition)

**Steps**:

- Go to *Run configurations* combo box.
- Click *Edit Configurations...*.
- Check *Allow parallel run* option.
- Click *OK*.

Answer (score 2):

Update April 2018:

On the "Run configurations" combo box, click "Edit Configurations". Then uncheck "Single instance only" option. Then click "Apply".

Then you can click the button "Run" any times you want, launching a new instance each time.

IntelliJIDEA Ultimate 2018.1

Answer (score 2):

You can go to edit configuration, allow multiple instance and add VM option where you can specify your port

for eg: -Dserver.port=8001

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this by launching a standalone java app which will spawn multiple threads per microservice and start them. You can find a sample code [here]: https://github.com/rameez4ever/springboot-demo.git

Answer (score 1):

Another note to reduce ambiguity:
What was called [Run Dashboard](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002311020-IntelliJ-Ultimate-edition-2018-3-and-Run-Dashboard) in a lot of sources in the past is now called **Services**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's called **allow parallel run** as of **2018.3** instead of **Single instance only**

Answer (score 1):

1. Package the application using mvn package.
2. Go to the folder where the packaged application jar is stored
3. Run java -jar [NAME_OF_THE_APPLICATION_JAR]
   --server.port=[DESIRED_PORT_NUMBER]

OR

1. Go to the application root directory
2. Run: mvn spring-boot:run
   -Drun.arguments="--server.port=[DESIRED_PORT_NUMBER]

That way you can start multiple instances of the same microservice at the same time using different port numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Goto "**Run configurations**" combo box, click "**Edit Configurations**". 
    Then unchecked "**Single instance only**" option. Then click "Apply"

**For Eureka Server:**

1.Run the application  without serve.port.

2.Add server.port =9999 in application.properties. Run the application.

Now browse Eureka dashboard, you will have 2 instances running.